# change file permission by gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I create .jar file and move it to dir, but I don't understand how I can change permission for this file after.

```groovy
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class':'com.asd.App',
                'Class-Path': 'com.asd'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    def file = file('/home/master/project/asd')
    fileMode = 755
    destinationDir = file
    with jar
}
```

Comment: Why not create the file with the correct mode in the first place?

Comment: Your fileMode is wrong. 755 is octal (base 8) but fileMode wants an integer (base 10). Did you try setting fileMode=493?

Comment: @Henry For me the mode defined in `jar {...}` is ignored. This can happen according to the docs: "It is dependent on the copy action implementation whether these permissions will actually be applied."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an `Exec` Task to change file permission. Add this in your `build.gradle` file

```groovy
task filepermission(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'chmod', '700', '<file_path>'
}
```

Run this using a `doLast` block. Your final `build.gradle` will look like this:

```groovy
task filepermission(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'chmod', '700', '<file_path>'
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class':'com.asd.App',
                'Class-Path': 'com.asd'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    def file = file('/home/master/project/asd')
    fileMode = 755
    destinationDir = file
    with jar
    doLast {
        filepermission.execute()
    }
}
```

now running `gradle fatJar` should change the file permission. Make sure you set proper path in the `filePermission` task

Comment: He wants to create the jar seomewhere then move to dir changing its permissions. I would use one task to create the jar, then a copy task (depending on the one that created the jar) to copy the jar in the dir and sets the proper pemissions by setting fileMode properly. As I wrote above 755 is wrong and should be replaced by the int (base 10) 493.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to embed it in an existing custom task, you use can [`Project.exec(Action<? super ExecSpec> action)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec(org.gradle.api.Action)).

```groovy
task changePermission {
  doLast {
    project.exec {
      commandLine('chmod',  '+x', '<fileLocation>')
    }
  }
}
```

The `project` is available in most task implementations because it comes from `AbstractTask.getProject()`.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the solutions above are unnecessarily convolurted. 
Posting this so I can find it next time I look for it:

```
distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from fileTree('src/main/scripts'), {
                filesMatching('myscript') { mode = 0744 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the solutions here, they are only catering to unix-esque operating systems like Linux and MacOS. For Windows, the `Exec` task within a `gradle.kts` file would look thus:

```
tasks {
    register<Exec>("makeFileExecutable") {
        workingDir(rootDir)
        commandLine("cmd", "755", "path/to/folderorfile")
    }
}
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: `cmd 755` ? What's that supposed to do?